# In React, how to set states after Provider's value changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are 2 components, `Header` and `Main`. They share the same context by

```
const SearchTerm = React.createContext();
const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState("");
<SearchTerm.Provider value={{ keywords, setKeywords}}>
          <Header />
          <Main/>
```

In the `Header` component, there is a search bar, and whenever its value changes, the handler will set its new value to the `SearchTerm` Provider's `keywords` field by `setKeywords(event.target.value);`.

Then, `Main` component will re-render because it is a comsumer of the `SearchTerm` Provider.

And in `Main` component, I need to use the updated `keywords` value to update a state named `results` (using the new keywords to search, set the newly gained results in a state using

```
this.setState({
    results: newResults
})
```

, and display the `results` state in the `Main` component.)

But there is a problem: I cannot call the `this.setState` function in `componentWillUpdate` or`componentDidUpdate` function because it will cause a `Maximum update depth exceeded.` error.

Then how am I supposed to update the `results` state every time the `keywords` value in the Provider changes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do a state update in a `componentDidUpdate`. You just have to make it something that is very specific. So in your case... you do a transition conditional. `if(!this.props.something && newProps.something || this.props.something !== newProps.something) { // i know something changed / is transitioning. Do something here }`

Comment: Do you use hooks in your component where you are using newResults?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thank you so much, it works! Do you want to make it an answer? I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are times when you want to update state in a lifecycle method that provides transitioning details (what the old properties are and what the new ones are changing to). `componentDidUpdate` would be one of those methods. The main issue you will have is making your conditional specific enough to not fire on every update (which would give you an infinite loop of `setState` -> `componentDidUpdate`).

Lets say you have a `Countdown` component that has a property `startDate`. And you want to update a state variable when a new starting date is passed to the component.

```
class Countdown Extends Component {
  state = { totalMs: 0 }
  componentDidUpdate(props) {
    if (!props.startDate && this.props.startDate || props.startDate !== this.props.startDate) {
      this.setState({totalMs: /* Some difference calculation of the start date till now in milliseconds that we can count down from */ })
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.totalMs / 1000} seconds till complete</div>
  }
}
```

So the key here is how you define a transition. `if (!props.startDate && this.props.startDate || props.startDate !== this.props.startDate)`. Lets break it down into a render cycle / visualization. The if statement has two conditionals...

1. the initial render conditional `!props.startDate && this.props.startDate`
2. the change of value conditional `props.startDate !== this.props.startDate`

so when rendering this component

```
<Countdown startDate={someStartingDateValue} />
```

on the first render cycle, componentDidUpdate would run and you'd notice `props.startDate` is undefined, however `this.props.startDate` would be the date value. On subsequent render cycles the `startDate` value would be equal and you wont setState. However if that `startDate` property has a new value passed to the component.. the change value conditional would fire